# How to implement Adaptive Lasso penalty for a Logistic regression in Python?

Tags: logistic, python, lasso, regularization, glmnet

I want to use an Adaptive Lasso instead of a standard Lasso because of the Oracle properties of the former. However, I cannot seem to find an option to implement an Adaptive Lasso for a logistic regression in Python. For example, the package [asgl](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.00472.pdf) lets one implement penalties such as an Adaptive Lasso, however, it only supports linear and quantile regressions. Unfortunately, switching to R (glmnet e.g.) is no option here because of company regulation.

Does anyone know how to implement Adaptive Lasso penalties for logistic regressions in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adaptive LASSO is a two-step estimator; check out section 3.1 of Zou ["The Adaptive Lasso and Its Oracle Properties"](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Ezouxx019/Papers/adalasso.pdf) (2006). (This is the original paper that proposed adaptive LASSO.) You can implement the steps separately. Let $p$ be the number of regressors in your model.

1. You start with a $\sqrt{n}$-consistent estimator of $\beta=(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_p)^\top$ such as the MLE.*
2. For $j=1,\dots,p$, you specify $\tilde X_j$ as $\frac{X_j}{|\hat\beta_j|^\gamma}$ for some $\gamma>0$ (e.g. $\gamma=1$). You then run a standard LASSO using these modified $\tilde X$s instead of the original ones. (See Section 3.5.)

*This requires the number of regressors $p$ to be less than the sample size $n$, $p<n$. Otherwise, you need to look for another $\sqrt{n}$-consistent estimator.

Comment: (+1) So just to make things extra straightforward, in python this approach could be implemented by using LogisticRegression with the inverse regularization strength C=10000 or some other big number. Then, take each column of your data and divide it by $|\hat{\beta}_j|^\gamma$ where $\beta_j$ comes from the _coef field of the LogisticRegression object and $\gamma$ is a positive hyperparameter; perhaps $\gamma=1$. Finally, create a second LogisticRegression object using the transformed X variables and a more reasonable C (chosen in the usual manner(s)).